# LinkedIn Web OAuth 2.0 verification requires typing in password even if user is already signed in on browser

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

Recently, we've been seeing that LinkedIn OAuth doesn't automatically allow users to sign-in automatically (even if they have signed in to LinkedIn with a different browser).

Expected Behavior (after signing-in to linkedin.com on same browser):

1. User clicks sign-in button
2. User is redirected to OAuth form & **auto-sign in occurs**
3. (If necessary) User is prompted for permissions

Current Behavior:

1. User clicks sign-in button
2. User is redirected to OAuth form & **is prompted to fill out username, password**
3. ...

We're using the standard [OAuth2 flow](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2). This is reproducible across at least Safari and Chrome on MacOS.

Is anyone else experiencing this behavior / know about why it's occurring?

Comment: We're running into this issue too -- would really like to know if it's more widespread / there's any workarounds

Comment: Yup, same issue here.